# making a parent div vertically scroll-able without changing the child divs height

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table created using divs.

HTML Code:

```
<div class = "content-table">
   <div class = "table-row table-row1">
       <div class = "left-align column1">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "left-align column2">Header</div>
       <div class = "left-align column3">
           <span><strong>Order Activities</strong></span><br/>
           <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                 <th>ACT NO</th>
                 <th>TYPE</th> 
                 <th>STATUS</th>
                 <th>REQUIRED-BY</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>01</td>
                 <td>D1PR01AG<br/> PHONEBOOKS (AUTOGEN) DO NOT COM/CAN MANUALLY</td> 
                 <td><br/>ACT</td>
                 <td><br/>15/06/16 17:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>08</td>
                 <td>Jackson</td> 
                 <td>ACT</td>
                 <td>20/06/16 17:00</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "table-row table-row2">
       <div class = "left-align column1">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "left-align column2"><strong>DAP</strong><br/>224466/1</div>
       <div class = "left-align column3">
           <span><strong>PHONEBOOKS (AUTOGEN) DO NOT COM/CAN MANUALLY</strong></span><br/><br/>
           <table style="width:100%">
               <tr>
                   <td>ACT</td>
                   <td>Action<br/> From table: JMINA Header: HC05C Instr: FIRST</td> 
                   <td>JMENHDC</td>
                   <td>20/06/16 17:00</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "table-row table-row3">
       <div class = "left-align column1">03-03-2016<br/>03:36:13</div>
       <div class = "left-align column2">Image Signature<br/>Notes</div>
       <div class = "left-align column3">
           <span><strong>Engineer EIN:</strong>607614772</span><br/>
           <span><strong>NAME:</strong>Signed By: Atish</span><br/>
           <span><strong>Are you able to capture customer survey and signature?:</strong>Yes </span><br/>
           <span><strong>Did the Openreach Engineer turn up when we said they would?: </strong>Yes</span><br/>
           <span><strong>Did they do the job needed ? (And if not, at least explain why they cpuldn't ?): </strong>Yes</span><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "table-row table-row2">
        <div class = "left-align column1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class = "left-align column2"><strong>DAP</strong><br/>224466/1</div>
        <div class = "left-align column3">
            <span><strong>PHONEBOOKS (AUTOGEN) DO NOT COM/CAN MANUALLY</strong></span><br/><br/>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>ACT</td>
                    <td>Action<br/> From table: JMINA Header: HC05C Instr: FIRST</td> 
                    <td>JMENHDC</td>
                    <td>20/06/16 17:00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "table-row table-row3">
        <div class = "left-align column1">03-03-2016<br/>03:36:13</div>
        <div class = "left-align column2">Image Signature<br/>Notes</div>
        <div class = "left-align column3">
            <span><strong>Engineer EIN:</strong>607614772</span><br/>
            <span><strong>NAME:</strong>Signed By: Atish</span><br/>
            <span><strong>Are you able to capture customer survey and signature?:</strong>Yes </span><br/>
            <span><strong>Did the Openreach Engineer turn up when we said they would?: </strong>Yes</span><br/>
            <span><strong>Did they do the job needed ? (And if not, at least explain why they cpuldn't ?): </strong>Yes</span><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here my each table-row doesn't have a fixed height. So, now I want to make the `content-table` class vertically scroll-able.

CSS

```
.content-table
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 437px;
}
```

When I add the above styles to `content-table` class each table row height become 437px. I just want to make the `content-table` class vertically scroll-able by without changing the `table-row` height.

How to fix this issue?

Edit: table-row CSS

```
.table-row
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Not seeing the problem. I don't see *why* the `table-row` div would change height based upon what you've posted here.. and I tested it... no apparent issue based upon what's here.

Comment: Not seeing the problem +1, btw here is an improvement that set the overflow-y to auto that the scroll bar will only be shown when necessary: https://jsfiddle.net/3at8wxwu/

Comment: @Scott The problem is `table-row` class height also become 437px. `table-row` height is depend on its content.

Comment: @LalindaSampath I'm not seeing that at all based upon what you've posted here. Table rows appear to retain their auto-heights... https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/jg9easLf/ Are you certain you don't just have a typo in your CSS, a missing bracket or semi-colon somewhere?

Comment: @Scott See the edit

Comment: @ZayLau See the edit

Comment: @LalindaSampath see my answer... easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your class in css
**.content-table** to **table-row**
as below

```
.table-row
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 437px;
}
```

Comment: This makes each row become scrollable not the table body.

Comment: Its because you have very less data inside your table. How ever inside the table body you can see the scroll bar in the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `height: 100%;` from your `.table-row` css. This property is causing the inline-blocks to be 100% the height of their parent (the contents-table).

```css
.table-row
{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
} 

.content-table
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 437px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "content-table">
   <div class = "table-row table-row1">
       <div class = "left-align column1">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "left-align column2">Header</div>
       <div class = "left-align column3">
           <span><strong>Order Activities</strong></span><br/>
           <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                 <th>ACT NO</th>
                 <th>TYPE</th> 
                 <th>STATUS</th>
                 <th>REQUIRED-BY</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>01</td>
                 <td>D1PR01AG<br/> PHONEBOOKS (AUTOGEN) DO NOT COM/CAN MANUALLY</td> 
                 <td><br/>ACT</td>
                 <td><br/>15/06/16 17:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>08</td>
                 <td>Jackson</td> 
                 <td>ACT</td>
                 <td>20/06/16 17:00</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "table-row table-row2">
       <div class = "left-align column1">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "left-align column2"><strong>DAP</strong><br/>224466/1</div>
       <div class = "left-align column3">
           <span><strong>PHONEBOOKS (AUTOGEN) DO NOT COM/CAN MANUALLY</strong></span><br/><br/>
           <table style="width:100%">
               <tr>
                   <td>ACT</td>
                   <td>Action<br/> From table: JMINA Header: HC05C Instr: FIRST</td> 
                   <td>JMENHDC</td>
                   <td>20/06/16 17:00</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "table-row table-row3">
       <div class = "left-align column1">03-03-2016<br/>03:36:13</div>
       <div class = "left-align column2">Image Signature<br/>Notes</div>
       <div class = "left-align column3">
           <span><strong>Engineer EIN:</strong>607614772</span><br/>
           <span><strong>NAME:</strong>Signed By: Atish</span><br/>
           <span><strong>Are you able to capture customer survey and signature?:</strong>Yes </span><br/>
           <span><strong>Did the Openreach Engineer turn up when we said they would?: </strong>Yes</span><br/>
           <span><strong>Did they do the job needed ? (And if not, at least explain why they cpuldn't ?): </strong>Yes</span><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "table-row table-row2">
        <div class = "left-align column1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class = "left-align column2"><strong>DAP</strong><br/>224466/1</div>
        <div class = "left-align column3">
            <span><strong>PHONEBOOKS (AUTOGEN) DO NOT COM/CAN MANUALLY</strong></span><br/><br/>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>ACT</td>
                    <td>Action<br/> From table: JMINA Header: HC05C Instr: FIRST</td> 
                    <td>JMENHDC</td>
                    <td>20/06/16 17:00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "table-row table-row3">
        <div class = "left-align column1">03-03-2016<br/>03:36:13</div>
        <div class = "left-align column2">Image Signature<br/>Notes</div>
        <div class = "left-align column3">
            <span><strong>Engineer EIN:</strong>607614772</span><br/>
            <span><strong>NAME:</strong>Signed By: Atish</span><br/>
            <span><strong>Are you able to capture customer survey and signature?:</strong>Yes </span><br/>
            <span><strong>Did the Openreach Engineer turn up when we said they would?: </strong>Yes</span><br/>
            <span><strong>Did they do the job needed ? (And if not, at least explain why they cpuldn't ?): </strong>Yes</span><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scrollbar is visible, but not scrollable

Comment: @LalindaSampath Do all the rows total a height greater than 437px? For example, is it scrollable here: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/jg9easLf/2/ ? If the total height of all rows is *less than* the 437 pixels, you'll see the scroll area, but there won't be a need to scroll. Are things scrollable in the snippet above? Unless you post *complete* CSS, this is something that could be "chased" all night.

Comment: If you change the .content-table height to 200px.. does it scroll then?

Comment: Another option is to leave the `height: 100%; there and change `inline-block` to just `inline`. https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/jg9easLf/3/ But I think you're going to run into the same issue.

Comment: Yes, when I change it to 200px, it becomes scroll-able. But .content-table height also become 200px

Comment: Okay, then your issue is a content-table that is greater in height than all the table-row divs stacked. Again, without more complete CSS, it's practically impossible to help further.

Comment: In order to *any* scrolling be possible the inner contents of the scroll area have to be *greater* than the area itself. You **can't** scroll a 437px tall container if the stuff inside it is only 300px tall.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when your `.content-table`'s height is set to 437px, it is expected all `.table-row`s' height are all extended to 437px since they are `height: 100%` which tell the browser to render their height match the `.content-table`'s height, try using `max-height: 437px` of `.content-table` instead

example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxavj8cv/1/

### Edit 1 -

Changed back `overflow-y` of `.content-table` to `scroll`
https://jsfiddle.net/vxavj8cv/2/

Comment: Scrollbar is visible, but not scrollable

Comment: @LalindaSampath may I know which browser and what version you are using? I have no problem on scrolling the .content-table with Google Chrome. You may want to change the overflow-y of .content-table back to scroll if this do the trick, see edit 1 for this attempt

Comment: I'm using google chrome Version 52. However when I changed the height of `content-table` to less than 400px it become vertically scroll-able. But `content-table` height also reducing.

Comment: when I change it to 200px, it becomes scroll-able. But .content-table height also become 200px